# Automate connections in 2 columns of nodes

Tags: node-editor

Here is a video proposal :

[image: Video proposal, blender, automate node connections by pairs]

Tell me what you think

Comment: I don't think it's possible to batch connect them by pairs.. Especially if inputs and outputs are of different types (yellow - 3 values for color and white - 1 value). You could link 2 of them and duplicate them after that if that's somehow eases the process.. or select them by 2 and press F.. or Ctrl+Shift clicking them to link to Viewer and grab another Mix on top of appeared link.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question, I actually want to connect inputs and outputs of the same type. The idea is to connect a big number of nodes (several hundreds or even a thousand if my computer can handle it)

Comment: The "Detach links" function is different, it's for *disconnecting* a node and, if it had an input and output of the same type both connected, connect the adjacent nodes together like this: http://i.imgur.com/rN6eYRX.png (before and after). Typically you just use the shortcut Alt-D, which does the same thing but also grabs the node and lets you move it out the way.

Comment: Yeah I actually figured it out yesterday, we discussed about making a clearer description here : https://developer.blender.org/rB13e7dddebdc1f3cecc3ab185919b5b9ebcbaa2df
I removed that from my question now.

Comment: I've got an idea for a simple workaround that would just require the ability to switch type (Shift+S) to a node group, but currently "Group" doesn't appear. Would that be hard to add ?

Comment: Another (maybe easier) workaround would require the ability to add reroutes to inputs instead of outputs. Does it also seem hard to code ?

Comment: The code itself isn't hard, understanding what you are really trying to do is. How would the code "know" which add to connect to which mix? Is it simply their location in the Node Editor?

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/D3ZJuDVyhPg) should make it clearer.

Comment: Just to notify that I added an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution (adding reroutes to all unused inputs and replacing them) :

[image: Blender, add reroutes to all nodes inputs]

If you prefer to read or didn't understand this rushed video :

So you have a bunch of nodes and you want to add reroutes to their inputs

1. add any node (doesn't matter which one since you'll delete it later)
2. move it on the left of your bunch of nodes
3. select your bunch of nodes and the new lonely one which you set as the active one
4. press <kbd>K</kbd> (with Node Wrangler enabled) to connect the lonely node to the bunch of nodes.
5. select and group the entire node tree except for the new lonely node which stays outside
6. in the group, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>left-click</kbd> drag on the group input links to add reroutes on them
7. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get out of the group
8. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to ungroup it
9. delete the lonely node you added previously
10. reorder your reroutes properly if some are not in the right place
11. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to arrange them perfectly

Voilà. Now you can replace those reroutes by any node with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. And if you need them to have specific parameters, don't forget Right-click > "copy to selected" to apply your changes from the active node to all the selected ones.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you select the nodes and hit F would connect them. I do not know what would happen if you connect with all the boxes selected.

Comment: I tried F but it does a big mess

Comment: "F" will try to connect them sequentially if they are all in a single row, like this: http://i.imgur.com/L3yvUgg.png

Comment: If you use "F" and then shift+D so you at least do a parallel work.

Comment: I can't use shift+D because I need to do this on nodes that already have other connections

Comment: I edited the question with a video proposal to make it clearer.